# Doing a series of equations with \begin{align*} where I want a \left[ to match with a \right] on another line

Tags: brackets

I would like to create a series of equations using `\begin{align*}` where a `\left[` matches up with a `\right]` on a different line, but it seems it won't let me do that. I was wondering what the best solution is.

This is the code I have written, which won't compile:

```
\begin{align*}
\Alt(D_n)(u)&=\left[\left(\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1-u^{2k}}{1-u}\right)\cdot\frac{1-u^{n}}{1-u}\cdot \frac{1-u}{1-u^{2}}\right)^{n}\left(\frac{1-u^{3}}{1-u^{2}}\right)^{-(n-1)} \\ &\cdot\prod_{k=4}^{n-1}(((1-u^{k+1})^{(-1)^k}(1-u^k)^{(-1)^{k+1}})^{n-k+1}(1-u^{2k-2})^{(-1)^{k}}(1-u^{k})^{(-1)^{k+1}})^{(-1)^{k+1}}\right]^{(-1)^{n}}
\end{align*}
```

but on the other hand this does compile

```
\begin{align*}
\Alt(D_n)(u)&=\left[\left(\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1-u^{2k}}{1-u}\right)\cdot\frac{1-u^{n}}{1-u}\cdot \frac{1-u}{1-u^{2}}\right)^{n}\left(\frac{1-u^{3}}{1-u^{2}}\right)^{-(n-1)}\right]^{(-1)^{n}} \\ &\cdot\left[\prod_{k=4}^{n-1}(((1-u^{k+1})^{(-1)^k}(1-u^k)^{(-1)^{k+1}})^{n-k+1}(1-u^{2k-2})^{(-1)^{k}}(1-u^{k})^{(-1)^{k+1}})^{(-1)^{k+1}}\right]^{(-1)^{n}}
\end{align*}
```

but I don't want to have two different pairs of square brackets for the two different lines like that.

Any help with figuring out what to do much appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to troubleshoot your problem - and much more likely that they will!

Comment: A `\left[`  will only match a `\right]` on the same line. Use `\right.` to close off the `\left[` at the start of the line and use a matching `\left.` on the next line. Actually, my preference is always to use `\bigl[` and `\bigr]` from amsmath   -- you will need `\usepackage{amsmath}`. There are also bigger variants `\biggl`, `\Bigl`, `\Biggl` ... I think that the `\left` and `\right` delimiters are often too big and prefer to choose the size myself using amsmath.

Comment: Another option is to use `multlined` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to 'close' or open a `\left[` or `\right]` with dummy delimiter called `\right.` and `\left.` at the right places. (This works for any of the `\left(` etc. bracketing commands)

`\Alt` is unknown to me, so I made it a dummy command, but an operator is better then.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Alt}{alt}
\begin{document}



\begin{align*}
\Alt(D_n)(u)&=\left[\left(\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1-u^{2k}}{1-u}\right)\cdot\frac{1-u^{n}}{1-u}\cdot \frac{1-u}{1-u^{2}}\right)^{n}\left(\frac{1-u^{3}}{1-u^{2}}\right)^{-(n-1)}\right. \\
 &\cdot \left.\prod_{k=4}^{n-1}(((1-u^{k+1})^{(-1)^k}(1-u^k)^{(-1)^{k+1}})^{n-k+1}(1-u^{2k-2})^{(-1)^{k}}(1-u^{k})^{(-1)^{k+1}})^{(-1)^{k+1}}\right]^{(-1)^{n}}
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

The scaling of the `[` might however not what one expects. And the lower part of the equation is too wide, in my point of view.

[image]

Comment: with the build in risk of ending with autoscaled fences that does not match up in size

Comment: @daleif: Yes, that's true.

Comment: There is an error in that code, `\Alt` now sets `(` in `\mathrm` ;-) LaRiFaRis is probably better

Comment: @daleif: In a sense, it's a an error, yes.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use a left right directive over several lines. It should be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Alt}{alt}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \Alt(D_n)(u)&=\left[\left(\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1-u^{2k}}{1-u}\right)\cdot\frac{1-u^{n}}{1-u}\cdot \frac{1-u}{1-u^{2}}\right)^{n}\left(\frac{1-u^{3}}{1-u^{2}}\right)^{-(n-1)}\right. \\ &\left.\cdot\prod_{k=4}^{n-1}(((1-u^{k+1})^{(-1)^k}(1-u^k)^{(-1)^{k+1}})^{n-k+1}(1-u^{2k-2})^{(-1)^{k}}(1-u^{k})^{(-1)^{k+1}})^{(-1)^{k+1}}\right]^{(-1)^{n}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

instead.

But your formula does not fit on one line as it stands right now. Here is an idea about how it would look better. Daleif added a slightly modified version using some `\{\}` for visual clarity plus a `\smash[t]` trick to save a little space. Egreg recommend to use smaller parentheses with some little horizontal space in front of the big operator. The final result:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Alt}{alt}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\Alt(D_n)(u)=
\biggl[
&
\biggl\{
\biggl(\,
\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1-u^{2k}}{1-u\hfill}
\biggr)
\cdot
\frac{1-u^{n}}{1-u\hfill}\cdot
\frac{1-u\hfill}{1-u^{2}}
\biggr\}^{n}
\biggl(\frac{1-u^{3}}{1-u^{2}}\biggr)^{-(n-1)}
\\
&
\begin{aligned}
\cdot\prod_{k=4}^{n-1}
\bigl[&\bigl\{(1-u^{k+1})^{(-1)^k}(1-u^k)^{(-1)^{k+1}}\bigr\}^{n-k+1}
\\
&\cdot(1-u^{2k-2})^{(-1)^{k}}(1-u^{k})^{(-1)^{k+1}}\bigr]^{(-1)^{k+1}}
\smash[t]{\biggr]^{(-1)^{n}}}
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it look better if the `\cdot` was inside the starting `[` and isn't there a `\cdot` missing before the very last line?

Comment: I'd consider just moving the alignment point in after `\Biggl[`, then we d not need so many `\quad`'s

Comment: I'll do that then (seems easier than just adding an extra answer, just to show a variation)

Comment: I'd use `\biggl` and `\biggr` throughout; `\Bigg` is too big. For instance, the exponents in the first line are at different heights.

Comment: That `\smash[t]` trick was handy, saved a bit of vspace

Comment: @egreg, I tend to agree, but I thought the `\biggl(` as a bit too close to the sums limits.

Comment: @daleif `\biggl(\,` is usually needed anyway (also with `\left` or `\Biggl`), when a big operator with limits follows.

Comment: @egreg, true, mostly I actually use `\Bigl(` around `\sum_i^j`, which loots better, but does not fit here because of the fraction

Comment: I'm not, as you, I have other things to do ;-)